# I want to make the AssetImage border circular more naturally

Tags: flutter, dart

I wrapped the AssetImage in a ClipRRect and used borderRadius.circular to make the image border circular. However, the image border doesn't become circular as I wanted. The Second photo is the one I want the first one to look like. What do I have to fix in my code? Or is there a new code I could try out?

[image: This is the weird photo]

[image: This is the photo I want]

```
  Flexible(
          child: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: [
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(233),
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage('assets/library.jpg'),
              height: 190,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `Image` `fit` property to something like `BoxFit.cover` or `BoxFit.fitWidth` or something else and see how it fits. Example:

```
Flexible(
    child: ListView(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  children: [
    ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(233),
      child: Image(
        image: AssetImage('assets/library.jpg'),
        height: 190,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
  ],
))
```